# Sphinx query strange result

Tags: php, sphinx

I have some problems with sphinx result.

When searching for normal words there are no problems. But if enter a nonsense words like "gghghghgh", the search result will not be empty. In fact, there is no text elements, that contain such query.

And i cant understand why that happend. Thanks!

Query:

```
mysql> select id from newsCache where match('ghghgh'); show meta;
+--------+
| id     |
+--------+
| 133576 |
|  82617 |
|  43613 |
|  38385 |
|  37042 |
|  55744 |
|  42380 |
|  44921 |
|  52825 |
|  54994 |
|  85116 |
| 132790 |
| 143505 |
|  86185 |
|  38634 |
|  40388 |
|  49325 |
|  49751 |
|  58548 |
|  80700 |
+--------+
20 rows in set (0.01 sec)

+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| total         | 348   |
| total_found   | 348   |
| time          | 0.009 |
| keyword[0]    | g200  |
| docs[0]       | 355   |
| hits[0]       | 433   |
+---------------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: You should provide example code.

Comment: @DanielO. Example of what? Sphinx config or calling query?

Comment: The calling query.

Comment: @DanielO. Has been added

Comment: Are you sure thats the exact query? it does not look syntactically valid, so wont even run. Also try running the quer 'manually' - eg using the `mysql` command line client, rather than via application (to issilate it to a problem with sphinx, not the application)

Comment: @barryhunter Has been added sql query

Comment: As mentioned in duplicate on sphinx forum, suspect you have metaphone morphology enabled http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=15721

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my config i found such parameters:

```
morphology     = stem_enru, soundex, metaphone
```

What i do:

1. Removed soundex morf engine
2. `Searchd --stop` - stop searchd service
3. delete index files (and delete the binlog as well!)
4. Reindex my RT index
5. Start searchd again

After that there is no strange result like "ghghghg0" =>"g200". All works fine.

Special thanks to @barryhunter for explanation of the solution on sphinx forum.

Hope this helps you.